# Python: Can I replace missing values marked as e.g "Unknown" to NaN in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am trying to calculate percentages, make graphs *etc.* with my DataFrame, but a lot of the missing values are bot marked as NaN—but instead '0::Unkown', '|Unkown' *etc.* This, of course, makes everything very messy.

I only want to include the "Yes/No" answers, which exists, but is highly outnumbered by the "0::Unkown"-string values.

Is there a way to get rid of them and convert them to `NaN`?

I have tried using `fillna()`, `lambda`, `replace`, *etc.* with multiple examples, but nothing seems to help.

This is a sample of my DataFrame column:

[image]

Comment: why replace is not working? can you provide some examples

Comment: edit you post and add a sample of your csv / dataframe

Comment: `df1 = df.replace('Unkown',np.nan,regex=True)` you can use something in the lines of this. Check if `Unkown` exists and replace with nan using `regex=True`

Answer (score 0):

##### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, '0::Unkown', '|Unkown'], columns=['gun_stolen'])

print(df)
```

##### Output:

```
  gun_stolen
0       NaN
1  0::Unkown
2    |Unkown
```

##### Code:

```
df.gun_stolen.replace({'0::Unkown' : np.nan, '|Unkown' : np.nan})
```

##### Output:

```
0     Nan
1     NaN
2     NaN
Name: gun_stolen, dtype: object
```

should do the job as written in the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

If `gun_stolen` column is supposed to be contain boolean values, the easiest way is to use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df['gun_stolen'] = pd.to_numeric(df['gun_stolen'], errors='coerce').fillna(0) \
                     .astype(bool).replace({True: 'Yes', False: 'No'})
```